# Different List initializing in GWT?

Tags: java, performance, list, gwt, collections

While learning GWT I faced another type of initialization.
I'm wondering what is the difference between:

```
 1) List<T> = new ArrayList<T>();
```

and

```
 2) List<T> = Lists.newArrayList();
```

Which one has advantages and why?

Comment: Here is the full source code: `@GwtCompatible(serializable = true) public static <E> ArrayList<E> newArrayList() {return new ArrayList<E>();}`. It's just a nice convenience method, I always prefer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only suppose:

When you work with generics it's not convenient to set T both in `List<T>` and `new ArrayList<T>();`
To resolve this drawback static helper methods are used:

```
List<T> = Lists.newArrayList();
```

Here type T is defined via type inference. A a rule such methods are implemented like this:

```
public static <T> List<T> newArrayList() {
    return new ArrayList<T>();
}
```

Comment: Exactly (see the videos "Using the Google Collections Library for Java" [part 1](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZeO_J2OcHYM) and [part 2](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9ni_KEkHfto)). The class `com.google.gwt.thirdparty.guava.common.collect.Lists` can be found in gwt-dev.jar, but it's actually a [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) (formerly [Google Collections](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/)) class.

Comment: If you're going to rely heavily on Guava, you should reference it directly. It's included in GWT only because some parts of GWT depend on it, but those dependencies may change out from under you in unexpected ways.